# Google Apps Script: Time Driven Triggers timezone issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to build a basic Time Driven Trigger in Google Apps Script to run a function at a specified date and time.

My code is as follows:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .timeBased()
    .atDate(2019, 12, 29)
    .atHour(12)
    .nearMinute(5)
    .create();
Logger.log("Trigger started!");
}

function myFunction() {
  Logger.log("I was triggered!");
}
```

However, each time I try to run the createTimeDrivenTriggers function I get the following error:

```
You cannot schedule an event in the past. (line 7, file "Triggers")
```

At the time of writing 2019-12-29 12:05 was not in the past (in my timezone). This made me think that the script is running in a different timezone than I am.. is that the case? If so, how do I set the script to default to the user's timezone?

This script is part of a Google Sheets Add On, I confirmed that my Google Sheets timezone is set to my local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer? Unfortunately, `atDate` and `atHour` cannot be used, simultaneously. In your case, `atDate` is used and the trigger is tried to be installed as `2019-12-29 00:00`. So such error occurs.

When you want to install the time-driven trigger for `2019-12-29 12:05`, how about modifying as follows?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .timeBased()
    .atDate(2019, 12, 29)
    .atHour(12)
    .nearMinute(5)
    .create();
```

To:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(2019, 11, 29, 12, 5))
    .create();
```

#### Note:

- In this case, please use `11` for December. Because the initial index of month for Date is `0`.

  > monthIndex: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

#### References:

- [atDate(year, month, day)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atdateyear,-month,-day)
- [atHour(hour)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#athourhour)
- [at(date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atdate)
- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.